# how do you add a formula in excel to remove invalid email addresses?

Tags: excel, email-validation

How do you add a formula into excel that will scrub all invalid email addresses?  I have a list I purchased of 1 million people that I would like to send my newsletter too, but I do not have much knowledge on using formulas.

Comment: What is your criteria for an email address being "invalid?" Would it just be malformed (i.e. missing the '@' symbol, missing the server, etc.) or are you trying to strip email address that are no longer active? Follow-up question, if malformed is what you're looking to filter, then why would a purchased list have those? Seems to me that if you paid money for it that it would come with complete addresses.

Comment: Just use RegEx, though 1 million e-mails seem like an awful lot to match.

Answer (score 1):

If your e-mails are in A column, go in the B column and in the B1 cell and copy paste this code:

```
=AND(FIND("@",A1),FIND(".",A1),ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)))
```

Then, go down and left on the B1 cell so you can copy and paste the code to the other cells.
Hope that helps!
At the valid e-mails, it will give you true.

Answer (score 0):

In some conditions if you want to go the weird route. Conditionally format the column to mark all good addresses green. Then sort by color. bam all your valid emails are at the top in a single range.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me (excel 2016):

```
=AND(FIND("@";B2);FIND(".";B2);ISERROR(FIND(" ";B2)))
```

props to @user3211903

Just replace all instances of "B2" with the name of the cell your email is located (eg. A1).